# reCaptcha V2 not returning a response in php

Tags: php, recaptcha

I have implemented the recapture code on the my html form with no problem.

I have the java script reference located in the header. I get a result for the g-recaptcha-response but when i try and verify it i get no result, i get nothing back, no error, nothing. I have checked my site and secret keys are correct. I have also put the $resp in the $status to see what the verified response is from google and it always shows as empty. I am unable to figure out what i have done wrong.

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MY.SITE.KEY"></div>
                      <br/>

                    <button  name="submit" type="submit">Submit Registration Form</button>
```

---

```
    if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))
    //your site secret key
    $secret = 'MY.SECRET.KEY';
    //get verify response data
    $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
    $resp = json_decode($verifyResponse);

    if ($resp->success==false) 
    {
        $proceed = false;
        $status .= "You entered the ReCaptcha field incorrectly!".$resp."<br />";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing a curly brace.

```
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {        
$secret = 'MY.SECRET.KEY';
$verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
$resp = json_decode($verifyResponse);

if ($resp->success== true) 
{
  //Do something
}}
```